# Using self join on a table to compare two columns based on a linked column in the same table

Tags: sql, self-join

I have the following:

**TableA**

```
ID | DocumentType | DocumentCode | DocumentDate | Warehouse | RefecenceCode  
---+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------    
 1 | DeliveryNote | DOC-001      | 2017-04-21   |    1      |     NULL   
 2 | Invoice      | DOC-002      | 2017-04-21   |    2      |    DOC-001
```

As you can see, the warehouse is different on each document and DOC-002 is related to DOC-001 through the information in `ReferenceCode` column (which means that was created starting from DOC-001 as a source document).

It is supposed for the DOC-002 to have the same information but sometimes might be different and in this case, I was tried to create a query (I think `self join` applies here) in order to check what information is different in the DOC-002 in this case compared to DOC-001, based on the reference code, but I couldn't managed to do it.

If someone could give me a hand, I'll be very grateful.

This is the SQL query:

```
select * 
from TableA tbl
inner join TableA tbla on tbl.id = tbla.id
where tbla.ReferenceCode = tbl.DocumentCode
```

Comment: What error did you get?   Please show the code you tried.

Comment: Please add a bit more source data and the desired result.

Comment: @TabAlleman - I have edited the post. I'm not getting any error, it just i don't get the result, no results returned.

Comment: You aren't getting any results because you're linking on ID, and 1 doesn't ever equal 2.  Your first step is probably to join on `tbl.DocumentCode = tbla.ReferenceCode`, but I'm still not sure what you want the results to look like.

Comment: @Jerrad - i would like to display only the line that has as a reference code another document and if contains different information compared to the source document.

Comment: What does "have the same information but sometimes might be different" mean? PS Please edit clarifications into your question, don't put them in comments. Please read and act on [ask]  and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You indeed want to join the table to itself.  But joining on the `ID` column won't work, because that column doesn't relate records to each other.  Instead, you need to join on the `DocumentCode` and `ReferenceCode` fields.  Then only include the records that have some difference (in this case, I'm only comparing the DocumentDate and Warehouse fields).

```
select tbla.* 
from TableA tbl
join TableA tbla on tbl.DocumentCode = tbla.ReferenceCode
where tbla.DocumentDate != tbl.DocumentDate
or tbla.Warehouse != tbl.Warehouse
```

Comment: It shouldn't take into consideration the DocumentType - this information is pure informative. It has to compare and if there are any differences between the source document and the destination document, it should display that line.

Comment: Just include whichever fields you *do* want to consider in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I would like to display only the row linked to another one through the `ReferenceCode`. I couldn't managed to achieve it...

Comment: Edit your question to include an example of what you want the results to be.